# Show that $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(2,3)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

Show that $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y) = 4xy-5x^2$ is differentiable at $(2,3)$.

> We need to show that for $(h,k) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $\displaystyle\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{\|f(2+h,3+k)-f(2,3)-\lambda(h,k)\|}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} = 0$ for $\lambda$ is linear.

**Solution Verification Requested**

So we examine

$$f(2+h,3+k)-f(2,3) - \lambda(h,k) = 4(2+h)(3+k)-5(2+h)^2 - [4(2)(3)-5(3)^2] - \lambda(h,k)$$

$$=4[6+2k+3h+hk] - 5(h^2+4h+4)-[-21] - \lambda(h,k)$$

$$=24+8k+12h+4hk-5h^2-20h-20+21 - \lambda(h,k)$$

$$-5h^2-8h+8k+4hk+25 - \lambda(h,k)$$

Now, we choose $\lambda(h,k) = -8h+8k+25$. Then we get

$$\displaystyle\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{|-5h^2-8h+4hk+25-(-8h+8k+25)|}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

$$= \displaystyle\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{|-5h^2+4hk|}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} \leq \displaystyle\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)}  -5\frac{|h|^2}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} +  \displaystyle\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} 4\frac{|hk|}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} $$

$$= -5 \displaystyle\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{|h|^2}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} - \Big( 4 \displaystyle\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{|h||k|}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} \Big)$$

$$ \leq -5 \displaystyle\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{|h|^2}{\sqrt{h^2}} - \Big( 4 \displaystyle\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{|h| |k|}{\sqrt{h^2}} \Big)= -5 \displaystyle\lim_{(h,k) \to(0,0)} |h| - \Big( 4 \displaystyle\lim_{(h,k) \to(0,0)} |k|\Big) = 0$$

And so we have shown that $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(2,3)$.

Comment: There’s also a theorem that if all partial derivatives are continuous in a neighborhood of the point, you get differentiability at the point for free

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is not correct.

1. You have lost an equals sign before the $-5h^2$ term.
2. You have left out one of the $8k$ terms in the equation with the limit.
3. Your use of the triangle inequality with $|-5h^2|$ is incorrect, there should not be a minus sign in front of that expression, and the following inequalities all seem to be nonsensical, not to mention you have added a spurious minus sign in front of the 4 term. Notice that $|h^2|$ is positive, as is $\sqrt {h^2}$, so how does your equation make sense?

If you remove the spurious minus signs and tidy it up, the basic idea of the solution appears to be correct.